Uncountable product of spaces with at least two points is not hereditarily normal
Suppose that $\prod_{i\in I} X_i$ is a product of spaces $X_i$ with $|X|\geq 2$ where $I$ is uncountable.
If all of the spaces $X_i$ are indiscrete, then $\prod_{i\in I} X_i$ is indiscrete, hence every subspace of it is indiscrete, and so the product is hereditarily normal.
On the other hand if each space $X_i$ is $T_1$, then $\prod_{i\in I} X_i$ contains a copy of $\{0, 1\}^I$ where $\{0, 1\}$ is the discrete two-point space, and hence a copy of $\{0, 1\}^I\cong \left(\{0, 1\}^\omega\right)^I$. Since Cantor space $\{0, 1\}^\omega$ contains a copy of $\omega$, it follows that $\prod_{i\in I} X_i$ contains a copy of $\omega^{\aleph_1}$. By theorem of Stone, $\omega^{\aleph_1}$ is not normal and so $\prod_{i\in I} X_i$ is not hereditarily normal. This is basically the proof here.
Suppose that $X_i$ are $T_0$ spaces. Can $\prod_{i\in I} X_i$ be hereditarily normal?

No, an uncountable product of $T_0$ spaces with at least two points is never hereditarily normal.
In fact, the product of indiscrete spaces is essentially the only example.
Theorem. If $X_i$ are not indiscrete and $I$ is uncountable then $\prod_{i\in I} X_i$ contains a copy of $\omega^{\aleph_1}$.
Assume that every $X_i$ is not indiscrete. There always exists a non-empty proper open set $U_i\subseteq X_i$ and taking two point set $Y_i$ such that $Y_i\cap U_i\neq \emptyset$ and $Y_i\cap (X_i\setminus U_i)\neq\emptyset$, we see that $Y_i$ is either discrete or the Sierpiński space $S$. Since $I$ is uncountable, $Y_i$ must be homeomorphic to one of the spaces $S$ or $\{0, 1\}$ for uncountably many $i\in I$. It then follows that $\prod_{i\in I} X_i$ contains either $\{0, 1\}^{\aleph_1} \cong \left(\{0, 1\}^\omega\right)^{\aleph_1}$ or $S^{\aleph_1} \cong \left(S^\omega\right)^{\aleph_1}$ as a subspace.
The Cantor space $\{0, 1\}^\omega$ contains a copy of $\omega$, and so in this case $\prod_{i\in I} X_i$ contains a copy of $\omega^{\aleph_1}$ which is not normal.
But the space $S^\omega$ also contains a copy of $\omega$. Take topology on $S$ to be that where open sets are $\emptyset, \{1\}, \{0, 1\}$. Let $A$ be the set of $x\in S^\omega$ for which there exists unique $n$ with $x_n = 1$. Note that $U_n = \{x\in S^\omega : x_n = 1\}$ is open in $S^\omega$. Then $U_n\cap A$ is a singleton containing the point $x\in S^\omega$ for which $x_n = 1$ and $x_m = 0$ for $m\neq n$. So $A\cong \omega$. $\square$
Corollary 1. An uncountable product of non-indiscrete spaces is not hereditarily normal.
Corollary 2. An uncountable product of $T_0$ spaces with at least two points is not hereditarily normal.
